# Save Image into project folder in web application

Tags: java

I have a requirement of saving the image into project folder. Which is a web application.
I am not able to figure out how to find the absolute path of my folder which I want to save the image. When I am trying to create empty folder and get the absolute path of that I am getting eclipse path.

Can anyone please help me in resolving the issue?

Here is some code I am trying to save the image:

```
public void saveCustomsLabel(byte[] array, Obj1, String str) throws userException {
    byte[] array2 = null;

    try {

       imageInByte = array;

        OutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        InputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInByte);
        BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(bis);
        File path = new File("Templates/Images/Image.bmp")
        ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "bmp", path);
```

Comment: Can you post some code so we can see what you are attempting to do?

Comment: sure it will give you the eclipse path , this is because it's the current directory  , so , if you can post the code and say when you want to save the image , you can get the help :)

Comment: Basically here I am getting the image in the form of Bytes from a webservice call.. :here is some code

Comment: public void saveCustomsLabel(byte[] label, Shipment shipment, String pkgId) throws userException {

        byte[] imageInByte = null;

        try {

           imageInByte = label;

            OutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            InputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInByte);
            BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(bis);
   File path = new File("Templates/Images/Image.bmp")
   ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "bmp", path);

Comment: where is the "Templates" folder ??? you need to enter the full path ,for  ex: if the "Templates" folder in portion `C`  , the path will be "C:\\Templates\Images\Image.bmp", understand me??

Comment: yeah my folder not in c: it is in my workspace project structure Templates/Images

Comment: yes i know it just example to explain what the path you need , you need to use the full path , so try to write the full path

Comment: so If I use the full path that is fine in windows.. If I want to run the application in Linux env.. how can I ?

Comment: aha i got it ,did this path "./Templates/Images/Image.bmp" work or not?

Comment: Still I am getting Resource not Found exception... :(

Comment: please make sure that you already have `Template` folder and `Images` folder inside it , and try to run the application out the Eclipse , and tell me the output

Comment: Are you calling saveCustomsLabel from a jsp by chance?  If you are, I can show you how to get absolute path in the jsp and you can pass it in as a parameter

Answer (score 1):

May be you should try deploying your project . On local machine the file goes to eclipse path.

Answer (score 0):

use the file location as "/Templates/Images/Image.bmp", this location should be in the same drive on which server is running ( in case of windows ). on linux it will be from root dir.

```
File path = new File("/Templates/Images/Image.bmp")
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897221/how-to-save-the-the-image-in-folder-on-disk-using-java) might help you

Try like this

```
File file = new File("/opt/image.png");

    if(!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.mkdirs();
            file.createNewFile();

            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(100,100,1);

             ImageIO.write(image, "JPG", file); 

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am trying to use the path you given in the above I am getting Resource not found exception... I have gone through the link which you provided.. I tried that approach... but it is saving the image in eclipse path ...

Comment: I am getting the bellow exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\Templates\Images\Image.bmp (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: Edited my answer with a code snippet that I tested and I was able to create the image. Just replace the way I was creating the BufferedImage object with yours.

Comment: Currently I am working on my Windows machine.. and it is a web application... I  tried to use the above snippet but still I am seeing the "java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified" exce[tion.. :(

Comment: Can you post your complete stacktrace and the actual piece of code.

Comment: File file = new File("/Templates/Images/label.bmp");
byte[] Image = bytes;
    if(!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();

           

             ImageIO.write(image, "bmp", file); 

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Comment: Does your "Templates/Images" folder exists or do you want to create these folder structures as well ? If you want to create the complete folder structure as well then you have to you "  file.mkdirs();" . I have edited my code snippet to take care of folder creations as well. Try now and let me know if that works or not

Comment: Did this worked because it is working for me. Can you post the complete stacktrace( not just the exception line like you posted the last time). So that I can look at what is wrong with your code